# Writing a New Line to a File

Tags: c, file, file-io, newline, file-descriptor

I am currently using the following commands to write to an output file for my program.  I want to take strings stored in a 2D array and write it to an output file I have set up, which is "url_storage.txt".

The example below shows how I have set up the file near the start of the program (i.e. the initial file descriptor declaration and call to open(...)) and shows the primary call to write(...), which occurs in a while loop (writing from each slot in the 2D array, or collection of strings/character arrays).  My issue is that I want to insert a NEWLINE character after each string, however, the following code does not yield a file with each string (or result of each write) on a separate line.  Is there any simple way for the write function to recognize that I want it to adhere to the newline character?  I also found that there is a function lseek(...) which will adjust my file position pointer (it looks like it's not really useful for new line adjustments).  Any suggestions on how to get that to point to the next line?

```
int fd2 = open("/directory/path/to/target/output/file/url_storage.txt", O_WRONLY, O_CREAT, 00777);

...
while(...){
      ...
      (void) write(fd2, (" %s \n", matches[ind]), strlen(matches[ind]));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
write(fd2, (" %s \n", matches[ind]), strlen(matches[ind]));
```

does not do what you think it does.  You're confusing `printf()` with `write()`.  The 'format string' `" %s \n"` is the first part of a comma expression and is effectively thrown away.  The string alone is written to the file.  You'll have to write the newline separately:

```
if (write(fd2, " ", 1) != 1 ||
    write(fd2, matches[ind], strlen(matches[ind])) != strlen(matches[ind]) ||
    write(fd2, " \n", 2) != 2)
    ...something went wrong...
```

Or consider using POSIX [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html) which is similar to `fprintf()` but writes to a file descriptor instead of a file stream.

```
if (dprintf(fd2, " %s \n", matches[ind]) != strlen(matches[ind])+3)
    ...something went wrong...
```

I've tried to follow what seems to be your intent, adding a space before and after the string, but were it my code, the trailing space at least would be omitted (no need for a space before a newline in almost any circumstances — except after the `--` that marks the start of a signature in email.  The preceding space might be necessary to separate the string from what went before.  However, I'd probably write:

```
if (dprintf(fd2, "%s\n", matches[ind]) != strlen(matches[ind])+1)
    ...something went wrong...
```

Or the equivalent with separate `write()` calls.

---

Incidentally, you wrote the equivalent of:

```
 const char path[] = "/directory/path/to/target/output/file/url_storage.txt";
 int fd2 = open(path, O_WRONLY, O_CREAT, 00777);
```

For complicated historical reasons, the prototype of [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is `int open(const char *path, int flag, ...);`, but only 2 or 3 arguments are valid and you've used 4.  You should have written:

```
 int fd2 = open(path, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0777);
```

but the compiler can't readily diagnose the mistake; after all, the prototype says 'any number of arguments'.  Also, unless you're writing a shell script, the file should not be executable (so 0666 instead of 0777), and I'd be willing to argue that it should not be publicly writable either, so 0664 or even 0644 would be better, notwithstanding the availability of a `umask` value.  Incidentally, one advantage of using a variable like `path` instead of a literal is that it is easier to report meaningful error messages using the file name if you don't have to repeat the string literal.

Comment: Well, the dprintf(...) certainly looked like a promising option, however it did not work.  I tried:  `dprintf(fd2, (" %s \r\n", matches[ind]));` (looked it up, it seemed very much like a normal print function, just with a file descriptor as its 1st argument)  I got the same results, no new lines.  Any suggestions?
My last option will be to try a follow-up call to write and write in the newline character \n and see what happens.

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine or a Unix machine?  On Windows, the `printf()` family normally deals with line endings for you, ensuring the ending is `\r\n` even though you just use `\n` in the code.  The `write()` functions categorically do not do that mapping.  I guess that `dprintf()` falls more closely with `printf()` than `write()`.  So, try adding a `\r` to the output, as the other person answering suggested.

Comment: Alright, so I decided to go with your approach and just simply omit the spaces (originally they were there just to see if I could get any kind of spacing between the URL strings--which wasn't happening).  This works and gives me each string on a new line, plus, I like the call to write buried within the if-statement to check if the function worked.
I'm on a Windows machine (using a Cygwin environment), but have been sftp-ing/remotely accessing a Linux account.  While I write the code on my Windows machine I use the command line on the Linux remote to compile and run the code.

Comment: I tested out both newline character approaches within the format string to dprintf(...) by the way:  both '\n' and '\r\n' work.  I guess going with the latter will be safer and work on both Linux and Windows environments?

Comment: Unless you've a strong reason for doing otherwise, I suggest using `fopen()` and `fprintf()`; it will be simpler for you, I think.  Carriage returns (`\r`) on Unix (Linux) are something of a nuisance; they work, but are not desirable.  Make sure you `fopen()` the file in text mode (not binary mode, so no "b" in the mode string) and `\n` in the source should work correctly for Linux when run on Linux and should work correctly for Windows when run on Windows.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.  I'll give `fopen(...)` a try--it looks much easier to use as per the API but just so you know, your recommendations for dprintf(...) worked as well--I think anyone using these functions should go with fopen(...).  I left the permissions at 777 just b/c I wanted to see if I could get the file to appear.  To note, it seems that with open(...O_WRONLY|O_CREAT...) only works if the file it is meant to open already exists...it did not appear to create the out.txt I expected (instead I just wrote my compilation script to create an empty out.txt that the open function could use).

Comment: Any insight as to why the way I had the call to open(...) set up above (aside from the syntactical errors) would not automatically create the output file "url_storage.txt" anyway?

Comment: Hmmm...because the second argument did not include the `O_CREAT` bit, the file had to already exist to be opened for writing.  Does this mean that you didn't check that `fd2` was a non-negative value before you used it?  Always check that file open operations succeed; it is very easy for them to fail in so many different ways, even when the program is correct.

Comment: Agreed, though I did have a check for the file creation, right after the call to open(...) actually, albeit a simple check:
`if(fd2 < 0){ printf("Error in creating a file, code:  %f\n", errno); exit(1); }`
As it turns out, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT vs O_WRONLY, O_CREAT makes a large difference in the I/O behavior of the program.  You're right the compiler doesn't catch this and leads to a run-time error (my check just produced a code = 0.00000).  However, before I followed your format, I had to rig my script to create the file beforehand to avoid the error, as open(...) did not create the file itself.

Comment: But I guess the moral of the story is make sure you have your flags in the <arg>|<arg>... format rather than as separate arguments (delimited by commas).